# Why is 0xF00 interpreted as NO, when the dec is not 0

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I discovered that

```
BOOL x = (BOOL)0xF00;
```

is `NO`... the value `0xF00` is non zero, yet still the result is `NO`

but this blows my paradigm, that BOOL is supposed to work as

```
NO == 0, YES == any other value
```

Why is it like that? Does it mean that checking

```
if (object) {}
```

is not safe?

Comment: `_Bool` works that way, but `BOOL` does not.

Comment: See also: ["BOOL's sharp corners" on BNR's blog](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/bools-sharp-corners/)

Comment: Sincerely, why does Apple fixed that in iOS three years ago but still haven't done that in macOS? That doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BOOL` is defined as a signed char, which is 8 bits. But `0xF00` requires more than 8 bits. So the compiler is taking the lowest 8 bits, which have a value of 0. When I try it, the compiler specifically warns about this problem:

```
warning: implicit conversion from 'int' to 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') changes value from 3840 to 0 [-Wconstant-conversion]
```

If you're going to assign arbitrary values to `BOOL` variables, then your paradigm about needs to account for how values are represented.

Comment: Does it mean that checking `if (object) {}` is not safe?

Comment: If you mean to check whether `object` is nil, it's safe, because the `if` check works differently. It's still clearer to write `if (object != nil) {}` though.

Comment: It does not use a `BOOL` variable, for one thing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40953767/evaluating-an-if-expression-behaves-differently-then-evaluating-a-bool-expressio

Comment: `if` check if its content is different from `0`, so yes, it works where `BOOL` variables fail.

Answer (score 1):

Casting to a one byte value truncated all higher bits... you can do this though...

```
BOOL boolyValue = !!0xffff00;
```