# Evaluating an if expression behaves differently then evaluating a BOOL expression

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

i assumed that the outcome of these two `if` statements is **ALWAYS** the same

```
BOOL tmp = (expression);
if (expression) {

}

if (tmp) {

}
```

but as discovered here
[Why is 0xF00 interpreted as NO, when the dec is not 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40953223/why-is-0xf00-interpreted-as-no-when-the-dec-is-not-0/40953506#40953506)

like when checking against a `0xF00` pointer, this might not be always the case...

How does evaluating an `if` expression behave differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` statement is defined in section 6.8.4.1 of the [spec](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf). The relevant section is:

> 2 In both forms, the first substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0.

You will note the lack of `BOOL` anywhere in that statement. `BOOL` doesn't exist in C; it's just a typedef to `signed char` provided by Cocoa. (`bool` exists in modern versions of C, but it's a different type, and still not related to the `if` statement.)

So if `expression` compares unequal to 0, but `tmp` compares equal to 0, then they will behave differently. This is the point Tom Harrington was making in the comments.